# Send value checked in toggle box = not sending value

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying for days now to get this toggle box to enter the value 1 in my db but without succes. The code i am using is:

```php
<?php

if(isset($item_id) && $item_id > 0) { 

  $setting = ModelMO::newInstance()->getOfferSettingByItemId($item_id);
 
  $enabled = isset($setting['i_enabled']) ? $setting['i_enabled'] : 0;

} else {

  $enabled = 0;
}

if(Params::existParam('mo_item_setting')) {
  $enabled = (Params::getParam('mo_item_setting') <> '' ? Params::getParam('mo_item_setting') : 0);

}

?><hr>

<link href="https://wirly.be/oc-content/plugins/make_offer/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css">

<span class="onoffswitch">

<h2><?php _e('Enable customers to make offer', 'make_offer');?></h2>

</span>

<div class="onoffswitch">       
                                                                         
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"  id="myonoffswitch" 
tabindex="0" value="1" " <?php echo ($enabled == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?> />

    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">

        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>

        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>

    </label>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Please i'm getting desperate and depressive about it so help me out ;-) What am i missing here?
Thanks for your reply's

Comment: To begin with, there's no `<form>` and no submit button?!

Comment: Try ro work with a boolean instead of 1 or 0. Why don't you keep the `$enabled` as simple as `$enabled = isset($setting['i_enabled']);`?